# "Did you like what you saw/see?"

Tags: past-tense, present-tense

So I heard this in a movie and I'm not sure if it's grammatically correct . . .

Should it be:

- 1.) *"Did you like what you* ***saw***?"

or

- 2.) *"Did you like what you* ***see***?"

Which one is right, you guys? I'm getting a bit rusty I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a matter of tense.

In present tense (ie you are looking at the object *now*):

> *Do* you like what you *see*?

In past tense (ie you were looking at the object yesterday):

> *Did* you like what you *saw*?

Comment: which is the answer for "did you like to eat chicken?" ? "Yes, I **like** to eat chicken" or "Yes, I **liked** to eat chicken".

Answer (score 2):

'Did' and 'saw' are both in the past tense, so 'Did you like what you saw?' is correct.

'Did you like what you see?' mixes past with present tense, which generally doesn't work.

If the sentence was in present tense, it would be, 'Do you like what you see?'

Answer (score 0):

The second form makes less sense.  If the first question is "padded" a little:

*Did you like yesterday what you saw yesterday?*

You can see that having both verbs past tense makes perfect sense!

*(excuse my alliteration)*

Answer (score 0):

"Did you like what you saw?" is absolutely correct sentence.

"Did you like what you see?" is not correct. This sentence is not expressing to past work.

Answer (score 0):

You could construct an example where "Did you like what you see?" makes sense, at least, even if it's not completely legal.

If person A changes their mind about an object, person B could ask them if they *did* like what they see [the object], implicitly asking about the time *before their mind changed*.

But that is a very worked example. It is not usually correct.

Answer (score -1):

"Did you like what you have seen?" Is a better option. This is one of the purposes the past participle form.

Using did already establishes the tense and makes it redundant, that's why you don't say "What did you said?" I just gave a better sounding option. When it comes to grammar rules, I can't say if it's wrong or right. They both SOUND wrong is my take.